# Foursquare API error No venues or groups specified returned when adding campaign

Tags: foursquare

Using the Foursquare Merchant API, I'm trying to add a campaign. I am able to add a special successfully. However, when using the special's id and adding a campaign, I receive the following error, "Foursquare2::APIError: other: No venues or groups specified. (400)".

Even after specifying both the specialId and venueId, I receive the same error. Although the foursquare docs state that only the specialId is required.

I am using the Foursquare2 ruby wrapper gem with my code additions to add a campaign

```
def add_campaign(options={})
  response = connection.post do |req|
    req.url "campaigns/add", options
  end
    return_error_or_body(response, response.body.response.campaign)
end
```

Having receiving a client object from the foursquare gem. I use the below code

client.add_campaign(:specialId => specialId, :venueId => venueId)

Any thoughts on why this is causing an error?

Comment: Can you post the specific HTTPS request (minus your oauth_token) going to our servers and the response JSON that comes back?

Comment: I'm using the foursquare2 gem to make the request. But basically the request is going to https://api.foursquare.com/v2/campaigns/add?specialId=4f374307d5fb890db4ea84e5&oauth_token=XXXX 

The response that I receive is {\"meta\":{\"code\":400,\"errorType\":\"other\",\"errorDetail\":\"No venues or groups specified.\"},\"response\":{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

venueIds and groupIds are not individually required, but one of them must be provided. I'll update the documentation to make this clearer. Thanks for pointing this out!